How Many Ways Can a $3 \times 3$ Grid Be Filled with Integers from 1 to 12 to Satisfy Certain Conditions?
In how many ways can a 3 × 3 grid be filled with integers from 1 to 12 such that all
three of the following conditions are satisfied: (a) both 1 and 2 appear in the grid, (b) the
grid contains at most 8 distinct values, and (c) the sums of the numbers in each row, each
column, and both main diagonals are all the same? Rotations and reflections are considered
the same.
What I’ve Tried:
I started by considering the general structure of a magic square and researched the conditions for sums being the same across all rows, columns, and diagonals.
I’ve attempted filling in the grid with the integers 1 and 2 placed in different positions, while ensuring the sum condition is satisfied, but quickly realized that many combinations don’t work, and I’m not sure how to proceed with the distinct value constraint.
I’ve also thought about the possibility of limiting the grid to only 8 distinct values, but it’s difficult to account for all the permutations while ensuring the magic sum condition holds across rows, columns, and diagonals.
I’ve considered using some trial and error for filling the grid, but the constraint of at most 8 distinct values combined with the sum condition makes it really challenging to narrow down the possibilities.
Overall, I’m struggling with how to balance all three constraints simultaneously and how to efficiently account for reflections and rotations. I’d appreciate guidance on how to approach this problem more systematically.
Can someone please walk me through how to solve the problem and also the answer?

Ah .. Found it myself: This is question 2/2/36 of the USA Mathematical Talent Search Year 36 (2024-25) Round 2 problem set (PDF link via usamts.org). Closing date is 2 December, 2024, so almost there (as of the writing of this comment).
